# How to show country flag in Magento language in header?

Tags: magento

I have added the following code in "app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/layout/page.xml"

```
<block as="store_language" name="store_language" template="page/switch/flags.phtml" type="page/switch">
```

and I have also called in **header.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language')?>
```

Still the language flag is not showing on Home Page.
I also put the language flag in `"skin/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/images/flag/flag_FLAGNAME.jpg"..`
then also it is not coming
If anyone knows this,please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the name of images you have put for flags?

Comment: In flags.phtml as you can see the flag images should be in .gif  format. i think you are doing the mistake here.

Comment: I have achieved this by following  https://webkul.com/blog/show-different-language-flags-instead-of-dropdown-magento/.

Comment: please help me the language flag is not showing in my home page.

Comment: Is it showing on other pages?

Comment: no when i am writing the code nothing is displaying in any of the pages

Comment: please tell me how to do this it is not comming anywhere in the front end

Comment: Did you followed the link i gave above?

Comment: yes the same thing i have done........I have added
<block as="store_language" name="store_language" template="page/switch/flags.phtml" type="page/switch"> in page.xml and added <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language')?> in header.phtml and put the flags in images/flags/en.gif.............
then also it is not showing

Comment: That is different from what i suggested :  https://webkul.com/blog/show-different-language-flags-instead-of-dropdown-magento/

Comment: ya i have tried this one also but same problem

Answer (score 0):

hello add below code may be help you

```
<block as="store_language_flag" name="store_language_flag" template="page/switch/flags.phtml" type="page/switch">
```

in header.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language_flag')?>
```